# Legend-placement in two different charts is different with same settings

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have two charts, and in both of them I want I want to place the legend in the upper right corner of the chart-area like so:

[image]

However when attempting to add a legend to the second chart, it is placed quite a bit lower, lower even that the top of the plot-area:

[image]

I have checked the sizes of the chart-, plot-, and title-fields, and they are roughly the same for both charts. At the moment I am quite stumped as to why the two legends behave differently, so any input on what may be the cause of it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two things I see (or don't see) that may cause it, but I don't know for sure (therefore, this is not posted as an answer)...1) is there data in the top image off screen to the left that has a higher peak than we cannot see. If so, it may cause the legend to land higher than if the peaks were lower. 2) the charts are different, in that there are more elements in the lower chart, therefore Excel will place things differently.

Comment: If I ever really, *really* need two charts to have identical formatting, I make the first one and copy / paste for the second one. It usually takes longer to go back and change all the data references than it would to re-do the formatting but it is sometimes worth it.